# Proper centering of text using CSS

Tags: html, css

What I want is to show "Loading..." as a simple text while page is loading and I want the text to be centered both - horizontally and vertically. I go through a lot of examples and now I have some sort of solution which seems to work, but I have some doubts that the effect will be the same all the time and that my code is even close to a good CSS.
  What I have is a index.php page where right after the `<body>` tag I have this:

```
<body>

        <div id="loading-standard-user">
            <p id="loading-standard-user-text">Loading...</p>
        </div>
```

Later on I have a function that take care for hiding the text when page is loaded, but what concern's me is the styling of the `<div>` and `<p>` tags.
  Here is my CSS:

```
#loading-standard-user {
  width: 100%;
}

#loading-standard-user-text {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: arial;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
```

I'm pretty sure that I have some unnecessary code and at the same time I miss something, one thing that I wonder is that my `font-size: 40px` which would have to mean that if I want my code to be vertically centered later on my `margin-top` should have value equal to half the size of my font, but visually it looks centered when `margin-top` is with the size of the font.
  Anyways any thoughts on the styling and where are my mistakes and how could I do it right?

Thanks

Leron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS code seems to do almost exactly what you want. The only problem with it that I can find is that your margin-top should be -50% of the height. Your div height is 40px (which is the font size), so your margin-top should be -20px to center it exactly.

In more detail: `top: 50%` sets the top of the text halfway the container. Then `margin-top: -20px` moves it up 20px to center it.

Edit:
If you want to use `em`, like suggested by @mgibsonbr, try the following CSS:

```
#loading-standard-user {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height:40px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2em;

}

#loading-standard-user-text {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-family: arial; 
}
```

Comment: Ah I see now that you also thought about margin-top yourself.. :)

Comment: Thanks, it seems that my eyes deceive me. I'll set it to `margin-top: -20px` and lave it that way. From the answers here I think that after all it's not that bad of solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `#loading-standard-user` seems unnecessary, your exampled worked fine (on Firefox and Chrome at least) with just the second rule. (the fact you're using `position: fixed` on the inner div makes where you place the outer irrelevant)

For the `top` and `margin-top` issue, it might look like it's centered, but that does not mean it actually is:

[image]

And if you're worried about resizing the text later, I'd suggest using `em` instead of `px` for setting your sizes, this way they will be automatically adjusted when the user resized the browser text. `1 em` is the height of the uppercase "M", while `1 ex` is the height of the lowercase "x".

(Unfortunatly, in practice I couldn't make it work with `em` while with `px` it worked just fine. Maybe I'm missing something?)

Comment: oops, seem I took too long to finish writing this answer, another one was already accepted... :P

Comment: Good idea to use `em` I guess. See my edit for a working CSS :)

Comment: Yeah, but yours is also useful, thanks for the info, centering seems to be a huge topic for CSS beginners, so every useful info is appreciated!